# Androidplot: How can I disable the X and Y axes lines while using the androidplot library?

Tags: android, androidplot

I am developing an app, for which I am using androidplot library.
My requirement is to draw a curved graph - very similar to what is shown [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=curved%20graphs&tbm=isch&imgil=weeLLIu3iGNIHM%253A%253BiI0YNZPS_xj9cM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fdocs.oracle.com%25252Fcd%25252FE28389_01%25252Fbi.1111%25252Fb32122%25252Forbr_graph003.htm&source=iu&pf=m&fir=weeLLIu3iGNIHM%253A%252CiI0YNZPS_xj9cM%252C_&usg=__pjW80B1qgtzU7mi4fje3mNg781Y%3D&biw=1366&bih=638&ved=0ahUKEwiGqP3t0JbQAhUEO48KHRukAGAQyjcIMA&ei=n3EgWMbcG4T2vASbyIKABg#imgrc=weeLLIu3iGNIHM%3A)

I am able to draw the smooth graph fine, but I want to remove the X and Y axes that are shown along with the graph. I need to display ONLY the waveform graph and not the X and Y co-ordinates. Is this possible? If so, how I can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful to see what you currently have, but going from the image you provided it sounds like you want to:

- Remove domain and range grid lines
- Remove vertices from the plotted line.

To remove domain & range grid lines, add this to your plot's xml:

```
ap:domainLineColor="@color/ap_transparent"
ap:rangeLineColor="@color/ap_transparent"
ap:domainOriginLineColor="@color/ap_transparent"
ap:rangeOriginLineColor="@color/ap_transparent"
```

To remove vertices from your plotted line, just pass in a null value for the vertex param of your LineAndPointFormatter's constructor.  For example, this would draw a read line with no fill or vertices:

```
LineAndPointFormatter myLineFormat = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.RED, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thank you @Nick. That helped